# Extended Interrupt 13, Reading an unformatted Disk

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, interrupt, diskimage

It's been a while since I did any ASM, and decided to once again try and write a small bootloader, testing with qemu. My issue is with interupt 13, for some reason the carry flag is being set, so the read is failing. Currently, my disk image looks like:

*512 Byte BootLoader* <- This (as far as I'm aware) Is block 0 in LBA

*Main Function* <- This would be block 1

Basically, with the 512 bytes the bios loads into memory, I want to load the next 512 bytes from the same drive. I can't figure out what's going wrong however. Hope I've given enough information.

Here's the code, the problem is with the second 0x13 interrupt, just before the jump to 0x7E00:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7C00]

; Prepare Stack Segment
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
    mov sp, 0x7A00              ; Move Stack into SP
    mov bp, sp                  ; Store current Stack Base

; Print Character to Make Sure Bootloader Has Reached this Point
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
    mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Character to Screen
    mov bh, 0x00                ; No Page Numbering
    mov bl, 0x07                ; White Text, Black Background
    mov al, 65                  ; Print Letter A
    int 0x10

; Check if INT0x13 Extentions are Supported
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
    mov ah, 0x41                ; Set Function 0x41
    mov word bx, 0x55AA          
    push dx                     ; Save old Drive Identifier
    mov dl, 0x80                ; Load 'Active' ID Into dl
    int 0x13                    ; Call Interupt
    jc short unsupported        ; If Extentions aren't Supported, Jump
    xor ax, ax
    add ax, 1                   ; Clear Carry Bit

    mov si, DAPS                ; Load DAPS Struct to DS:SI
    mov ah, 0x42                ; Read Functions (AL Ignored)
    mov dl, 0x80                ; Active Boot Drive (Commented Out Due to Line 24)
    int 0x13
    jc short unsupported        ; If something goes wrong...
    jmp 0x7E00                  ; Jump to main

; Errors 
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
    unsupported:
    mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Letter F, Gives Indication of Failure
    mov bh, 0x00
    mov bl, 0x07
    mov al, 70
    int 0x10

    success:
    pop dx                      ; Pop Original Drive Identifier
    jmp $

; Fill Out Rest of Bootloader
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
times 494-($-$$) db 0

; Memory Data Structures and Other Variables
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
    ; Disk Address Packet Structure (Used For Loading Rest of OS)
    DAPS: db 0x10               ; Size of Structure (16 bytes)
          db 0                  ; Always 0
          db 1                  ; Number of Sectors to Read (1x512)
          db 0                  ; Always 0 
          dw 0x7E00             ; Target Location for Reading To
          dw 0                  ; Page Table (0, Disabled)
          dd 1                  ; Read from Second Block
          dd 0                  ; Large LBAs, ignore

    db 0x55, 0xAA               ; Add Boot Record Signature

main:
    mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Character to Screen
    mov bh, 0x00                ; No Page Numbering
    mov bl, 0x07                ; White Text, Black Background
    mov al, 66                  ; Print Letter B
    int 0x10

    jmp $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem ended up being simple, the code was right. But because the final image was 525 bytes, instead of a multiple of 512 bytes, the read broke. Just had to pad my image out with 0s to make the image size 1024B so the read could get all 512 bytes.

(Obviously probably a much better idea to not have a tiny unformatted disk like this, but for learning purposes this is all I really needed)